# How do I replace text using Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm using android studio to make an app for college, but I'm very new to using Java. I'm currently trying to replace text in a fragment (if that's what it's even called) but I can't seem to get it working. I currently have some code set up that detects if you're swiping in a certain direction, and want to replace some text upon swiping in a direction.
This is my code currently:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Swipe position";
    private float x1, x2, y1, y2;
    private static int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
    private  GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    public boolean onHomeScreen;
    {
        onHomeScreen = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialize gesturedetector
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(com.example.tindiertest1.MainActivity.this, this);

        //Initialize navigation bar
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        //start at home screen
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

    private  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            if (!onHomeScreen) {
                                onHomeScreen = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_messages:
                            selectedFragment = new com.example.tindiertest1.MessagesFragment();
                            if (onHomeScreen) {
                                onHomeScreen = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_settings:
                            if (onHomeScreen) {
                                onHomeScreen = false;
                            }
                            selectedFragment = new com.example.tindiertest1.SettingsFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };

    //Override on touch event


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (onHomeScreen) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                //starting to swipe gesture
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    break;

                //ending time swipe gesture

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    y2 = event.getY();

                    //getting value for horizontal swipe
                    float valueX = x2 - x1;

                    //getting value for vertical swipe
                    float valueY = y2 - y1;

                    if (Math.abs(valueX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        //detect left to right swipe
                        if (x2 > x1) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Right is swiped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Right Swipe");
                        } else {
                            //detect right to left swipe
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Left is swiped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Left Swipe");
                        }
                    } else if (Math.abs(valueY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        //detect top to bottom swipe
                        if (y2 > y1) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Bottom is swiped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Bottom Swipe");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Top is swiped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Top Swipe");
                        }

                    }

            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to replace the text in this fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/random_nummer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home fragment"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What is the correct way to replace the "Home fragment" text upon swiping in a certain direction?

Comment: so ... what does this have to do with java**script**

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added the javascript tag instead of java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
TextView rn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.random_nummer);
rn.setText("My text.");
```